# Operation error when trying to delete a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to delete a document; when I do so, I get the following error:

> OperationError: Could not delete document (unrecognized write concern field: write_concern)

Here's how I am deleting my document:

```
appointmentInformation = appointment.objects.get(booking_id=str(request.args.get('booking_id')))
appointmentInformation.delete()
```

I'm tying to delete the `appointment` object based on its `booking_id`; it throws me that error. I'm using Mongo:

```
mongoengine==0.8.7
pymongo==2.8.1
```

I am looking for a solution for the Mongo version I'm using and do not plan on updating.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Have you tried to set the write concern in your call or elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Figured; there wasn't way around but to upgrade my library to 0.9.0. It started working then.